# How to add styling to a Kendo UI Alert

Tags: css, kendo-ui

How can I add styling to the Kendo UI Alert, like the background of the title and button? I can set the content's background color by adding a background-color style to the div. Just not sure how to go about doing that with the Title and the button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').on('click', function() {
    myalert("I'm an Alert");
  })
});

function myalert(content) {
  $("<div></div>").kendoAlert({
    title: "My Title",
    content: content
  }).data("kendoAlert").open();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.1.117/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the alert dialog in your browser developer tools, you can see the classes used and then override the css.

e.g.

```
.k-dialog.k-alert .k-dialog-titlebar {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;      
}

.k-dialog.k-alert .k-button {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;      
}
```

**[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uSArE)**